# How to extract full model information after Support Vector Machine (SVM) training?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I am using "sklearn.svm" to do basic SVM training. For SVC, is there a way to print out the model details described in documentation:

[image]

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(C=10.0,kernel='linear',probability=True,verbose=True)
clf.fit(X, y_)
```

NOTE: I am not talking about the parameters that can be reached with "get_params" or "set_params". I am refering to the actual coefficients that are determined as the result of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation of SVC:

```
Attributes: 

support_ : array-like, shape = [n_SV]
    Indices of support vectors.
    support_vectors_ : array-like, shape = [n_SV, n_features]
    Support vectors.

n_support_ : array-like, dtype=int32, shape = [n_class]
    Number of support vectors for each class.

dual_coef_ : array, shape = [n_class-1, n_SV]
    Coefficients of the support vector in the decision function. For       
    multiclass, coefficient for all 1-vs-1 classifiers. The layout of   
    the coefficients in the multiclass case is somewhat non-trivial. 
    See the section about multi-class classification in the SVM 
     section of the User Guide for details.

coef_ : array, shape = [n_class-1, n_features]

      Weights assigned to the features (coefficients in the primal  
      problem). This is only available in the case of a linear 
      kernel.

      coef_ is a readonly property derived from dual_coef_ and  
      support_vectors_.

intercept_ : array, shape = [n_class * (n_class-1) / 2]
      Constants in decision function.
```

You can derive from this attributes all information about your model.

For example : `clf.n_support_` will return `n_support_` of your model.